# How to get the aspect ratio of an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I need to get the original aspect ratio of
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiT4u.png)

Expect to get the original aspect ratio of the image

Answer (score 3):

Pass the "getAspectRatio()" function an "img.src" parameter.
The actual dimensions of the picture will be taken, after which a check will be made whether the picture is in portrait or landscape format.
As a result, the function returns aspect ratio of the image.

```js
function getAspectRatio(image) {

    const w = image.naturalWidth;
    const h = image.naturalHeight;

    let aspectRatio;

    if (w > h) {
        aspectRatio = w / h;
    } else {
        aspectRatio = h / w;
    }

    return aspectRatio;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to know how many times one side is bigger than the other, then the other options suit your needs. But if you want an actual *ratio*, try this function and pass it an `HTMLImageElement`.

```
function aspectRatio(image) {
    const height = image.naturalHeight;
    const width = image.naturalWidth;

    const gcd = (...arr) => {
        const _gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));
        return [...arr].reduce((a, b) => _gcd(a, b));
    };

    const gcdResult = gcd(width, height);

    return `${width / gcdResult}:${height / gcdResult}`;
}
```

Note: I didn't write write the GCD function myself, I stole it from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-8.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const aspectRatio = yourImage.naturalWidth / yourImage.naturalHeight;

console.log('Aspect ratio:', aspectRatio);
```

Comment: Explaining your code is a good way to share learning and is more useful than just having the question-author copy-paste your solution without understanding it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).